# Reading file content line by line into a matrix

Tags: c, fopen

I was trying to write a function that could copy a text file content line by line to a matrix, so this is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define rows 5
#define columns 12

void file_to_matrix(char *matrix[]){
    FILE *file = fopen("swamp.txt", "r");

    if(file==NULL){
        printf("File error");
        exit(1);
    }

    int y=0;

    for(int x=0; (matrix[y][x]=fgetc(file))!=EOF; ++x){
        if(matrix[y][x]=='\n'){
            ++y;
            x=0;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main(){
    char *matrix[rows];

    file_to_matrix(matrix);

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
            printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I tried to compile and run it on Windows and Linux but the only thing that it manages to do is giving me errors that are practically useless like:

```
"Stopping due to fatal error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

or

```
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
```

Comment: For one thing, you have created a matrix of pointers and then try to stuff chars into it. What do you think char *matrix[rows]; does?

Comment: What data do you think the definition `char *matrix[rows];` points at?  The short answer is 'none', so you get crashes. You need to allocate space for the columns.  The simplest would be `char matrix[rows][columns];` — but your call.  Change the function interface, too; it is no longer accurate.

Comment: The message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` is a valuable message that tells you that you screwed up (or, if it isn't your program, someone else screwed up).  And the `core dumped` part means you could run a debugger on the program and the core dump and you might be able to find out more about what went wrong when the crash happened.  The Windows message says much the same; I'm not sure that you can do a post mortem analysis with a debugger on Windows.

Comment: I've corrected your title, as you're not *writing* anything - fgetc() reads. Also, the first error you describe (*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*) is impossible to get in C, because a) there is nothing even remotely resembling an *object* in the code you've posted).  and b) C does not have *objects*.. Enable hints and warnings for your compiler, and read those hints and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory for each element of `matrix`. This is the same exact mistake as writing:

```
char *s = "string";
```

As the first act of the program, loop through `matrix`, and call `malloc` for each cell:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (!(matrix[i] = malloc(MAXLEN))) [
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Note: we check the return value of `malloc` to ensure no errors have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

with your code, i think the matrix in the file will restricted (you define rows=5 and columns=12). so i think again to write a code that can be flexible, no need to set max row or column again. here we go

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc realloc

//file read function. returning string with splitted new line
//ex: (note: newline is '\n' (ENTER))
//test.txt:
//10 20 30(space)(newline)
//40 50 60(space)(newline)

void file_to_matrix(char *filename)
{
    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *buff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); //temp string
    int *matrix_row = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); //temp matrix row
    int **MATRIX = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)); //this will become the final matrix
    int index_buff = 0, index_MATRIX = 0, index_matrix_row = 0; 
    while (1)
    {
        char c = getc(file);
        if (c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (c=='\n') //if c meet newline, then add the matrix row to final matrix 
        {
            (*(MATRIX+index_MATRIX)) = matrix_row;
            index_MATRIX++;
            MATRIX = realloc(MATRIX, sizeof(MATRIX)*(index_MATRIX+1));
            matrix_row = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
            index_matrix_row = 0;
            printf("\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (c==' ') //if c meet space, then buff wil converted to int
        {
            int num = atoi(buff);
            printf("%d ", num);
            (*(matrix_row+index_matrix_row)) = num;
            index_matrix_row++;
            matrix_row = realloc(matrix_row, sizeof(int)*(index_matrix_row+1));
            free(buff);
            buff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
            index_buff=0;
            continue;
        }

        //add buff with c
        (*(buff+index_buff))=c;
        index_buff++;
        buff = realloc(buff, sizeof(char)*(index_buff+1));
    }
    fclose(file);


    //clearing the dynamic memory
    free(buff);
    for (int i = 0; i < index_MATRIX; i++)
    {
        free(MATRIX[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    file_to_matrix("test.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

test.txt:

```
10 20 30 
40 50 60 
70 80 90
```

if you confused with the test.txt format, i will explain again:

```
10 20 30(space)(newline)
30 40 60(space)(newline)
70 80 90(space)(newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, I think your solutions are very clever but I was looking  to an easier one.

After a little bit of trial and error I think I found a solution that it isn't very generalized but it's simple and it seems to work fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS <n of rows>
#define COLS <n of columns>

void file_to_matrix(int rows, int cols, char matrix[rows][cols], char file_path[]){
    FILE *file = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("File error");
        exit(1);
    }
    int y=0;
    for(int x=0; (matrix[y][x]=getc(file))!=EOF; ++x){
        if(matrix[y][x]=='\n'){
            matrix[y][x]='\0';
            ++y;
            x=-1;
        }
    }
        fclose(file);
    }

int main(){
    char matrix[ROWS][COLS+2];
    file_to_matrix(ROWS, COLS+2, matrix, "file path");
    for(int i=0; i<=ROWS; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", matrix[i]);
    }
}
```

Thank you again for your answers